# How to grab all items from all DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this issue where all the rows in mt Dataframe contain more than one item. I would like to iterate throughout the whole Dataframe and append each row item into a new list but I'm unsure on how to do this as of now.

```
IPs
0   [172.16.254.1, 192.168.1.15, 255.255.255.0]
1         [192.0.2.1, 255.255.255.0, 192.0.2.1]
2                                [172.16.254.1]
3                                     [0.0.0.0]
```

This is my current output - and I would like to take each item per row in the Dataframe and append to a list

```
curled_ips_list = []
ip_addresses_found = []
ip_address_format = (r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b')
with open(website_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as curled_ips_file:
    found_ips_reader = pd.read_csv(curled_ips_file, names=['IPs'], delimiter='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, engine='c')
    found_ips_reader = pd.Series(found_ips_reader['IPs'])
    curled_ips_list = found_ips_reader[found_ips_reader.str.contains(ip_address_format)]
    curled_ips_list = curled_ips_list.str.findall(ip_address_format)
    curled_ips_list = pd.DataFrame(curled_ips_list)
    curled_ips_file.close()
```

Not receiving any error messages as of yet, but unsure on how to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned your output that you need, I am assuming you need the following.

```
#Load your IPs in a dataframe as the one that you have mentioned above.

iplist = df['IPs']

[ip for sublist in iplist for ip in sublist]
```

```
['172.16.254.1',
 '192.168.1.15',
 '255.255.255.0',
 '192.0.2.1',
 '255.255.255.0',
 '192.0.2.1',
 '172.16.254.1',
 '0.0.0.0']
```

Comment: glad to help anytime